# How can I create a picker similar to the pickers in the Android settings?

Tags: react-native

In the settings of my phone I have, among other things, this:

[image: Example of Picker]

It has a **title** ("Sleep"), a **value** ("After 30 minutes of inactivity", which is actually an expanded version of "30 minutes"), and if you touch it it shows you a list of **options** to choose, which display in their short forms rather than in the expanded form.

I'm seeing this so often that I thought it would be standard. However I can't find out how I can create such a control with React Native. The `Picker` component is apparently more limited.

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown

Comment: So there's no standard way? I'm baffled. Is there a standard way in Android but not in React Native perhaps? (By "standard" I mean either without a third-party package or with a third-party package that is so commonly used that everyone considers it obvious.)

Comment: You can write your own native android package if you want and then import than module in react native